# When using Symfony's ACL, is it better to use a JOIN query or an IN array query?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

This question builds upon discussion at [How to filter my Doctrine queries with Symfony ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858642/how-to-filter-my-doctrine-queries-with-symfony-acl/23247026)

- There is a Class/Entity e.g. products
- It's mapped to a database table
- Each row represents an object (a product)
- We're using ACL to allow/restrict access to products

With this in mind, **how do we query to get a list of all the products a user has access to?**

Going through each product, and checking if the user has access to is out of question... This will quickly go bad.

In the previous discussion, we were toying with either IN array, or a JOIN query.

**IN ARRAY APPROACH** Get a list of product ids a user has access to (from the `acl_entries table`), and then do an IN array query on the `products table`.

**JOIN APPROACH** Join the `acl_entries table` with the `products table`.

(Note, in both cases parent_acls aren't being used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at time complexities for both cases:

**IN ARRAY APPROACH:** Entity Table of `M rows`, with ACL entries array of `size N` (rows in the ACL table not relevant here)

**TIME COMPLEXITY**: O[N*log(M)]

---

**JOIN APPROACH:** Entity Table of `M rows`, with ACL table of `N rows`

**TIME COMPLEXITY**: O[M + N]

---

In practice we generally have a situation like,

**IN ARRAY**

```
N=10,000
M=1,000,000
O=>60,000
```

**JOIN**

```
N=10,000
M=1,000,000
O=>1,010,000
```

And in theory, the worst case scenario for in array would be

**IN ARRAY**

```
N=1,000,000,000
M=1,000,000,000
O=>9,000,000,000
```

**JOIN**

```
N=1,000,000,000
M=1,000,000,000
O=>2,000,000,000
```

---

**What does this mean? Summary/TL;DR**

If each User is only granted access to a fraction of the objects in an entity use IN array.

If each User will have an ACL entry for every Object of an Entity, use JOIN. Although the gains will not be of several orders of magnitude (unless you have trillions of products), so you might still want to use IN array.

In both cases, use ACL only when absolutely necessary! Voters FTW!